# KustoServiceError when using application authentication

Tags: python, azure-data-explorer

I am having trouble trying to set up a connector to Kusto using the Kusto client library for Python.

I managed to make it work using the `with_aad_device_authentication` method, by doing the following:

```py
KCSB = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_device_authentication(KUSTO_CLUSTER)
KCSB.authority_id = AAD_TENANT_ID

client = KustoClient(KCSB)

KUSTO_QUERY = "Table | take 10"
RESPONSE = client.execute(KUSTO_DATABASE, KUSTO_QUERY)
```

which requires me to authenticate by going to a web page and entering a code provided by the library.

However, when I am trying to connect to the database using the `with_aad_application_key_authentication` method it throws me

```
KustoServiceError: (KustoServiceError(...), [{'error': {'code': 'Forbidden', 'message': 'Caller is not authorized to perform this action', '@type': 'Kusto.DataNode.Exceptions.UnauthorizedDatabaseAccessException' ...
```

which I don't understand since I have granted my application with the following permissions: Azure Data Explorer (with Multifactor Autentication) and Azure Data Explorer.

I have been struggling on this for a while and I couldn't come up with a solution. Does anyone have any idea of what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible reasons:

1) You did not give the app permission on the database itself. Permissions on the Azure data explorer resource (we call it the 'control plane') using the "access control (IAM)" button allow your app to do management operations on the cluster (such as adding and removing databases), while permissions in the database itself allows doing operations within the database such as creating tables and doing queries (we call it the 'data plane'). Please note that you can also provide permissions to **all databases** in the cluster by clicking on "permissions" button in the cluster blade.

In order to fix it, click on the database in Azure portal and once you are in the database blade, click on the 'permissions' button and give the app permission (admin, user, viewer etc.). see screenshot below.

2) You did not provide the any of the three required datapoints correctly (appId, appKey and authority id)

Here is the relevant screenshot for adding permission in a specific database:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding some more context.
Granting your application delegated permissions to ADX only allows your application to perform user authentication for ADX resources, but it does not grant the application itself any roles on your specific ADX resource.

The answer above guides you how to do that.